# create extremely random trees classifier inside or outside the loop

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a number of sample matrices (mxn) in X_sample.
Each matrix has the same number of rows (same m) but with different number of features (diff n).
Example of matrices in X-sample are: 1000x40, 1000x35, 1000x30,1000x25.
I have the following (much simplified ) code example about my question:

```
Y_train =
Y_test =
clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=500, max_depth=None,max_features="auto",
                           min_samples_split=1, random_state=0)

for X_data in X_samples:
    X_train = X_data[0]
    X_test = X_data[1]
    clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    pred_res = clf.predict(X_test)
    .....
```

I create a classifier outside the loop with the parameter `max_features="auto"`.
I perform different classifications inside the loop using sample matrices with different number of features. My question is if the classifier will adjust the value  of `max_features` based on the actual size of X_train (actual number of features)every time the loop performs the fit operation. The parameter  `max_features`with value "auto" should get the actual value equal to the square root of the number of features. 
That is, should I have the creation of the classifier outside the loop or inside the loop? Is there a way to read the actual value for the parameter `max_features`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
The `fit` function does not change the estimator.
See [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/index.html#estimated-attributes).

Comment: But the `ExtraTreesClassifier` seems not to export the actual `max_features` when the `__init__` parameter is set to `"auto"`.